# Add disk to (and increase size of) bitnami owncloud storage

Tags: linux, hard-drive, virtualbox, partitioning, owncloud

I am using bitnami owncloud in a virtualbox environment and the installation is on a 2 TB disk. I would like to add another disk (1 TB) and have the actual storage of owncloud files on the secondary disk.

When I look at the owncloud storage it says:

```
You have used 2.3 MB of the available 12.9 GB
```

So the first question is: how do I increase that number from 12.9 GB to X GB?

Secondly, when I ssh into the machine and use `df -h`, I get:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        15G  1.3G   13G   9% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            997M  4.0K  997M   1% /dev
tmpfs           201M  316K  200M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           1001M     0 1001M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

So it looks like the 12.9 GB I have are coming from the `/` partition. If I want to add that 1 TB disk to the VM, how do I get owncloud to put the files there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check where is your data location (normally is /var/lib/owncloud/data) and after creating partition and filesystem mount the new filesystem there. Do not forget to copy existing files to new filesystem.
In config.php you have line like

```
'datadirectory' => '/var/lib/owncloud/data',
```

which point to the data directory

Comment: Thanks, I see this now. Now it just turns into a VM question of how to mount a physical disk to a VM!

Comment: Welcome. Please ask different question about that